# Insert again elements from one list to the prior list

Tags: c#, list, insert, removeall

Here is my situation. I have 2 list of the same type. Imagine the names like these. FullList and ElementsRemoved. So in order to avoid the database roundtrip, anytime I delete an element from the fulllist I added to the list of ElementsRemoved in case of regret's user so he can revert the deletion.

I was thinking to loop inside my ElementsRemoved to insert them again into the FullList from where initially were removed.

There is any way to do this as simple with List Methods.

Something like

```
FullList.Insert, Add, ..... (x =>
```

in order to reduce line code and optimized?

Comment: just thinking here, you could just keep them all in one list and set a flag like Enabled = true/false for each object.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but what about just jusing `ElementsRemoved.Remove` and `FullList.Add`?

Comment: what is your `type`?which field in your type do you use to uniquely identify each type..also show us your attempt..

Comment: @csharpler Then the "removed" items will all be put back at the end, not where they belong.

Comment: Hi @chancea, I will love to use a state like Enabled in my collection but I can't change the structure of the entity at this point. I collaborating with other team members and I not allow to modify the structure.

Comment: @Servy. I didn't realized that behaviour!!!! It's sure that they will be added at the end and not at their original position!!! Damn... I'm starting to think that my only solution is to get the elements from the cache!

Comment: @MaximusDecimus Okay well just continuing to think out loud here, this may hinder performance, but you could again leave all the elements in the `FullList` and only add removed items to the `ElementsRemoved` list but keep them in the `FullList` then if you want to know if an element exists just do like a `!FulllList.Contains(ElementsRemoved[x])`

Comment: Thanks!!@chancea!! you are right!Look at the 4th answer! Sten Petrov's advising to create a little class in my fron-end with the fields required. Maybe that would help me! I gonna try it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your front end make a class that holds a bool and your object:

```
public class DelPair<T>{
   public bool IsDeleted{get;set;}
   public T Item{get;set;}
}
```

Now instead of using a list of objects use a list of `DelPair<YourClass>` and set `IsDeleted=true` when deleting.

This pattern will also allow you to track other things, such as `IsModified` if it comes to that.

Based on OP comment that he's using an ENTITY class and needs it to function as such:

One option is to make your DelPair class inherit ENTITY. Another *may* be to put implicit casting operator:

```
...
   // not exactly sure about the signature, trial/error should do :)
   public static implicit operator T(DelPair<T> pair) 
   {
      return pair.Item;
   }
```

Comment: It's look very interesting but then how can I bind this info to my repeater! Because I should create a List of this DelPair<ENTITY>

Comment: You can put in implicit casting or inherit from your ENTITY

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting the item from your database consider using a flag in the table.

For example consider this entities table (written in TSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
   ,Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
   ,IsDelete BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

This way you can set the `IsDelete` bit when the user deletes the entity which will prevent the data from being lost. The data can be pruned on a job in the off hours.

The would lead to only needing one list instead of keeping track of two lists.

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
}

public static void UndoDelete(IEnumerable<Entity> fullList, int[] removedIds)
{
    foreach(var entity in fullList.Where(e => removedIds.Contains(e.Id)))
    {
        entity.IsDelete = false;
    }
}
```

In case you cannot modify your application.

You can simply add the entities back in.

See [`List(T).AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)

```
var entitiesToAdd = new[] { 2, 3, 4 };

var entitiesToInsert = ElementsRemoved.Where(e => entitiesToAdd.Contains(e.Id)); 
FullList.AddRange(entitiesToInsert);
```

Comment: his requirement is not table design. He may have the same design you have proposed. His question is "There is any way to do this as simple with List Methods"

Comment: I added in a proposed solution as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Romoku!!Really! but imagine that I not allow to change the database nor entity structure. I have 2 lists. One of them loaded with the database data and the other one with my little trick. To remain the data in web application I save them in viewstate!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an element having a field id which uniquely identifies it.

```
class Element{public int id;}
```

In that case you can do this

```
FullList.Add(ElementsRemoved.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.id==id));
```

In case you want to add all elements use AddRange

```
FullList.AddRange(ElementsRemoved);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method

```
FullList.AddRange(ElementsRemoved);
```

But consider doing this

```
public class YourClass
{ 
     public string AnyValue{get;set;}
     public bool IsDeleted{get;set;}
}
```

And you have list like this **List < YourClass> FullList**. Now whenever user removes any item you just set the

```
IsDeleted = true
```

of the item that is removed. This will help you in keeping just one list and adding removing from the list